# jQuery script fires twice? Perhaps live event is firing twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am building an application using the latest version of PhoneGap, jQM and jQuery 1.8.0. So far so good except for this tiny and annoying problem I came across.

I have my show.html linked from the index.html that contains the following code:

```
<div id="search"> contains search bar and submit button </div>
<div id="list" style="display:none;"> 
      <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true"> </ul>
</div>
```

The ul tag is empty because the list will be dynamically appended to it using ajax when the submit button is clicked. I didn't want to display the #list div at first so I set the display to none.

So this works fine, when the submit button is clicked, it will send an ajax request to the server and append the items to the list. It will also hide the search div. This works alright as well!

Now the problem comes in, I added a window.scroll function to detect when the bottom of the page is reached.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#pageID", function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                success: function(data, status){
                  $('#search').hide();
                  $('#list').show();
                //append to list div and refresh list here
                }
        });
    });
    //detects bottom of page
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop()+200 >= ($(document).height() - ($(window).height()))) {       
            console.log('end of the page');
                        lastPostFunc(); //infinite scroll function
        } 
    });  
});
```

This prints 'end of the page' two times to the firebug console! This script exists in between the head tag.

Is there anyway to just make it print once? I need this because I implemented my own endless scroll function and the problem is causing my ajax request to post twice to the server. The function works great but is not the cause of the problem because even when I commented lastPostFunc() out, it still prints to the console twice!!

**Edit:** Personally, I don't think the answers given so far are wrong, they are correct but they do not help me solve the problem. Maybe I need to rephrase things better. I copied my code and pasted it on a standalone page, it prints only once, so my code actually has nothing wrong with it and it's working like it should be.

Therefore, I was wondering whether there's something else that's causing it to print twice after submitting the form. My form and my results page is **ON** the same page. Does this means it caused the live event to work twice? Thus, causing it to print to the console twice on pageshow? If I am correct, is there anyway to work around this and making it only print **ONCE**?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: by the way, don't use .click(), it's deprecated. Make use of: .on('click', function() { // code here }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I finally solved it.

Apparently all I have to do is to add this line of code to it:

```
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        if (reach bottom) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            console.log('End of the Page');
        } 
    });
```

And it works! Stopped printing twice for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will actually write output to the console more than two times. The problem lies within your condition:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop()+200 >= ($(document).height() - ($(window).height())))
```

Because for every scroll within this area the condition will evaluate to true. You could change it to:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - ($(window).height())))
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. didn't print anything to the console instead. It doesn't output more than two times though. It outputs two times continuously in a go.

Comment: Sry I just tried this in Chrome, worked fine. Remove the + 200, that should work in Firefox too.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but it doesn't work. It still prints twice to the console. I tried it in Firefox and in Chrome. Before submitting the form, I pasted some dummy text to fill up the page, the window.scroll fires fine! It prints once! But after I submit it and when I scrolled down, it prints twice in a go. I hope that makes sense. Really appreciate the help you gave me.

Comment: try switching the .on to .live that should fix it :)

Comment: I tried live before. But I read that it's deprecated since 1.7.2 so I switched to using on. Doing that still makes it print twice. :(

Comment: On a side note, I tried adding this '$(document).off('pageshow', '#catalogsearch');' in my .on funciton. It caused the log to be printed once after submitting the form and printing my second ajax call nicely. But the form is useless after that. I can't access the event anymore.

Answer (score 0):

May this will solve your problem

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if( (jQuery(document).height() < (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 200))&&(jQuery(document).height() > (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 99))) {        
    console.log('test')                                         
    }
});
```

//Update

```
    var lastlogtime= null;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if( (jQuery(document).height() < (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 200))&&(jQuery(document).height() > (jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height() + 99))) {
        if(((lastlogtime+600)<(+new Date())) || (lastlogtime== null)){
            //your scroll logic
            console.log('test')         ;
            lastlogtime=    +new Date();                            
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help but it didn't work. Instead, it didn't cause anything to be printed at all.

Comment: It still doesn't print anything. I'm not sure whether you seen my other reply to the other user but if I used my original code, it still prints twice to the console. But before submitting the form, I pasted some dummy text to fill up the page, the window.scroll fires fine! It prints once! But after I submit it and when I scrolled down, it prints twice in a go. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes. It still causes the same problem. :(

Comment: I have updated the answer try it with both with your code and stand-alone.let me know what happens.

Comment: Still prints twice after submit. But I tried it standalone on a page with dummy text only. It prints once. :( Which is weird. Does it have something to do with my pageshow event? Is it loading twice because I submitted my form? But submitting the form only cause the search div to hide. And appends results to the div.

Comment: Still print twice, unfortunately. On a side note, I tried adding this '$(document).off('pageshow', '#catalogsearch');' in my .on funciton. It caused the log to be printed once after submitting the form and printing my second ajax call nicely. But the downside is that the event is not executed anymore after that.

Comment: @user1771355:Here is some example of infinite scroll last one is somewhat similar so maybe this will help you http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: It's not the infinite scroll problem. I commented infinite scroll out. It still prints twice. :(

Comment: @user1771355:As per my understanding what happeing with the code is when data is loaded it scrolls the scrollbar and the code fires again and it logs in the console.so what I am suggesting is after logging check time and if it's less than a second since last logging dont log it again.

Comment: Ahh! I think I get what you mean. Thank you! I will try that out now! :) Just to make sure, do I need to bind the time checking to a .change event?

Comment: @user1771355:I have updated the answer which may help you to build the logic.

Comment: nulltest
1351243639503test
test
nulltest
1351243639590test
test

this is what firebug returned me. It's still the same. :( Thanks for the hard work though!! But it doesnt seem to have any effect.

Comment: @user1771355:you did not remove my test code.I have edited it.

Comment: Doesn't matter if I removed it or not because firebug still gives me test test. And data was posted twice. Sorry.